# FrameLayout, works fine on emulator(API8), but missing some widgets on emulator API 17

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using an Activity with a FrameLayout, this is shown correctly in the emulator(API 8), but there are missing the last 2 buttons from the 1. LinearLayout, when I start the activity in another emulator API 17.
Please help me.

```
public class OnActivityResultActivity extends Activity
{
  private Button        button  = null;
  private Button        button1 = null;
  private TextView      text  = null;
  private static final int  Mars  = 0;
  private static final int  Moon  = 1;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
  }
```

Now the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/selection"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal">
      <Spinner android:id="@+id/Spinner01" 
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"/>
    <RadioGroup android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/radiogroup1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="player" android:checked="true"/>
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rm" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="modify table"/>
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rc" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="create table"/>
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rd" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="delete table"/>
    </RadioGroup>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" android:id="@+id/startbutton" android:onClick="goPlay"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Exit" android:id="@+id/exitbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"   
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:id="@+id/play"
       android:padding="10dp">
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/frage"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="40sp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:text="@string/app_name"
          android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
       <TableLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/antwort1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"></Button>
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/antwort2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"></Button>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/antwort3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"></Button>
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/antwort4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"></Button>
          </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>

       <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <ProgressBar
             android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
             android:max="8"
             android:progress="0"/>
          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Erreichter Spielstand \nclick in center to start the again"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
       </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<RadioGroup android:layout_height="match_parent">` tries to fill the entire layout. You probably want `wrap_content` instead

Comment: many thanks for your answer, after the correction the layout works fine.